# Next steps in a react/redux sound dispatch app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm building a react/redux drum machine app for a freeCodeCamp challenge, and I've got the buttons done and the connections made for onClick to dispatch an action with the url link to the sound as a property, but I'm hung up on what I need to create as a reducer for this to work how I'm wanting.

You can view what I've got so far here: https://codesandbox.io/s/k29r3928z7 , and you can ignore the pieces for the Hello/Goodbye switch at the top as that was just for me to understand the flow of React/Redux to start. My main question is what should I be doing with state in this case? Pressing the button won't really change the state at all, so I'm not sure what I should be doing at the 'new state' step of creating a reducer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with the specific goals of the freeCodeCamp challenge, however if you're wanting the app to play the correct sound when the user clicks any one of the buttons shown, you can achieve this by updating your `drumClickHit` action as follows:

```
export const drumClickHit = url => {

  //Create an audio object from the url provided to the action
  const sound = new Audio(url);

  //Play the audio object immediatly
  sound.play();

  return {
    type: "CLICKHIT",
    url
  };
};
```

To illustrate the relationship between action creators and reducers, you could achieve the same result as above, by adding the following "CLICKHIT" case to your reducer as follows:

```
case "CLICKHIT": {

  //Create an audio object from the url provided to the action. 
  //Get the url from the action
  const sound = new Audio(action.url);

  //Play the audio object immediatly
  sound.play();

  return state;
}
```

In the case of your app however, logic for audio playback is better placed in the action, rather than reducer.

Comment: Thank you! Does that mean that in this case, it's not necessary to include this action in the reducer at all?

Comment: Hey you're welcome :-) - technically speaking, you don't *need* to use redux to achieve any of this. For instance, you could add a `playSound(url)` method directly to the `DrumMachine` component that contains the same logic I posted in the answer. You could then update your `<button>` in the `drumObj.map(..)`  callback to look something like this: `onClick={() => this.playSound(x.url)}`

Comment: Lol this is the problem I keep running into when trying to learn React/Redux. Every time it gets hard to do something it ends up being easier to do it all without either React or Redux. I have nothing large scale to apply it to!

Comment: Very true! https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367 - usually redux becomes valuable for larger apps, consisting of many views and nested components, that all need to be synchronised from shared state. In the case of your app though, it's quite achievable without redux.

Hope you've found this answer to be of use!

Comment: Very much appreciated. For the sake of understanding how it works, I'll keep using Redux even if I don't really need to. Hopefully one day I'll have a large project which I can apply it to.

Comment: Great, please feel free to PM me if I can be of any assistance to you in your learning :-)